# Bounding rectangle of ellipse

Tags: elliptic-curves, bezier-curve

In a stale branch of the code base I'm working on, I found an interesting algorithm to go from the SVG definition of an elliptical arc, to Bézier curves. This is a question about a small but crucial part that I don't understand.

FYI an updated and fully corrected version of [the algorithm](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/svg/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/svg/renderers/path/impl/EllipticalCurveTo.java) is now published on the `develop` branch of iText 7; it is confirmed to work for all tested scenarios, so I'm only looking for an explanation as to why the angle $\chi$ is calculated as it is.

input: starting point $(x_1, y_1)$, ending point $(x_2, y_2)$, semi-axes $a$ and $b$, and the guarantee that $a$ is parallel to the horizontal axis

intermediate output: a *bounding rectangle*, a *starting angle*, and an *extent*, to be consumed by an [established function](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/canvas/PdfCanvas.java#L1079).

The salient part of the algorithm goes like this, in pseudocode:

$$r_1 = \frac{x_2 - x_1}{-2a}$$
$$r_2 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{2b}$$

$$\kappa = \arctan{(r_1 / r_2)}$$
$$\lambda = \arcsin{\sqrt{r_1^2 + r_2^2}}$$

$$\chi = \kappa \pm \lambda (+ \pi ?)$$

Then, for all scenarios for $\chi$, try

$$center = (x_1 - a * \cos \chi, y_1 - b* \sin \chi)$$

Once $center$ is known, calculating the bounding rectangle is trivial, and the angles can also be attained with relative ease.

And now the question: I understand most of the algorithm, but I must admit that I have no idea why $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ together form the angle we're looking for.

[image: From input to output]

Comment: Could you include an annotated illustration?

Comment: @JorisSchellekens not sure if it helps, but this is input information (all colored items on the left) and intermediate output requirements.

Comment: Definitely helps. But could you also annotate the image with (x1, y1) and (x2, y1) etc?

Comment: I think the idea is the following : an ellipse is a squished circle. Since the axes of the ellipse are parallel to the axes of the plane, if you apply the linear map $(x,y) \mapsto (x/a,y/b)$, then the ellipse is mapped to a circle (this linear map is implicitely used in the definitions of $r_1$ and $r_2$). The angles $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ are angles in this circle, not in the ellipse. Once you get the coordinates of the center of the circle, work back to the ellipse (formally via the inverse of the linear map; here, it is implicitely done in the definition of $center$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D. Thomine’s comment beat me to the punch. The parameterization $C+(a\cos t,b\sin t)$ of an ellipse can be understood as the image of the unit circle $(\cos t,\sin t)$ under scaling and translation, and the key to understanding this part of the algorithm is to map everything back to the unit circle.

So, let $C$ be the as-yet-unknown coordinates of the ellipse center, and let $P_1' = (x_1',y_1') = (x_1/a,y_1/b)-C$ and similarly for $P_2'$. (The unknown $C$’s will cancel and drop out of the calculations pretty quickly.) We then have $(-r_1,r_2)=\frac12(P_2'-P_1')$, i.e., half of the segment $P_1'P_2'$, and $\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2}$ is the length of this half-segment. Rotating this vector 90° produces $(r_2,r_1)$, which is the direction of a line through the center of the circle and the midpoint of $P_1'P_2'$. The interpretation of the two angles $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ becomes pretty straightforward with that:

[image]

$\chi=\kappa\pm\lambda$ are the angles to $P_1'$ and $P_2'$ (with some ambiguity as to quadrant), which are then the correct inputs to $C+(a\cos\chi,b\sin\chi)$ to obtain $P_1$ and $P_2$.

It’s also possible to solve for the center of the ellipse more directly: it must lie on one of the intersections of the congruent ellipses centered at $P_1$ and $P_2$. If you subtract the equation of one of these ellipses from the other, you get the equation of a line that passes through the two intersection points. The problem then reduces to the intersection of a line and an ellipse, which can be solved quite readily. The resulting expressions are *much* more complex than the ones in the algorithm in your code, though.

Comment: Since this is a "found algorithm": wouldn't it be easier to just do basic geometry in the unit circle, and find the center point as the fourth vertex of a rectangle consisting of $P_1$', ($P_1$' - $P_2$') / 2, and ($P_1$' + $P_2$')/2 ?

Comment: @blagae Unfortunately, that doesn’t work because you don’t actually know the coordinates of $P_1'$ and $P_2'$: they both involve an unknown translation by $C$. The algorithm in the code works because this $C$ cancels when you compute $P_1'-P_2'$, but it’s still present in two of the three points that you’ve listed. They might not even form a right angle!

Comment: In the circle, I think you're guaranteed to have a right angle because, as you said, "Rotating this vector 90° produces $(r_2,r_1)$, which is the direction of a line through the center of the circle and the midpoint of $P′_1P′_2$" (which is  $(P'_1 + P'_2)/2)$. But your point is valid indeed, now that I think of it: we don't know how to translate back.

Comment: @blagae On the unit circle, the missing corner of the rectangle is always the origin. In vector form that particular calculation is $P_1'+((P_1'-P_2')/2-P_1')+((P_1'+P_2')/2+P_1')$, which always gives $0$. Not very helpful, since, as you’ve noted, you don’t know how to translate back. That translation is exactly what you’re trying to find in the first place! Even if you expand in terms of the original coordinates $P_1$ and $P_2$, that expression will always evaluate to $0$.